# JavaScript form validation on submit.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have a little problem with JavaScript form validation. I would like validation error to show only after the user clicks submit.

Right now validation occurs when you type in any input field.

Example:

HTML:

```
<form id="contact_form" method="post">

    <li>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name">
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" name="email">
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" name="subject">
    </li>
    <li>
        <textarea type="text" placeholder="Message" name="message"></textarea>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="send-button">
    </li>
</form>
<div class="validate-error"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {

  $('#contact_form').validate({
    errorElement: 'div',
    errorClass: 'validate-error',
    focusInvalid: false,
        rules: {
            name: 'required',
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            subject: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            message: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
            $(".validate-error").html("All fields must be completed before you submit the form.");
        }
    }); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZrfhU/215/

Comment: Where is `.validate()` coming from? Are you using [this jQuery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your code into function and then trigger function with the click of the button like so:

```
function validate() {
    // your code
}

$(".send-button").click(function() {
    validate();
});
```

Check demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/ZrfhU/217/

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/ZrfhU/216/

```
$('.send-button').click(function(){
```

if you just want to validate it during click.

do keep in-mind that people with java-script disabled will not have any
form validations

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using [this jQuery form validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org), you need to set `onkeyup` and `onfocusout` to `false` in the `.validate()` object. By default, it will validate your form every time either of those events are triggered.

```
$('#contact_form').validate({

    onkeyup:false,
    onfocusout:false,

    errorElement: 'div',
    errorClass: 'validate-error',
    focusInvalid: false,
    rules: {
        name: 'required',
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        subject: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        },
        message: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
        $(".validate-error").html("All fields must be completed before you submit the form.");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateForm() {

    var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
    var name = document.myForm.name.value;

    if (name == "") {
        document.getElementById("errormsg").innerHTML = "Name must be filled out";
        document.getElementById("errormsg").style.display = "block";
        return false;
    } else if (email == "") {
        document.getElementById("errormsg5").innerHTML = "Email Id must be filled out";
        document.getElementById("errormsg5").style.display = "block";
        return false;
    } else if (!email.match(mailformat)) {
        document.getElementById("errormsg5").innerHTML = "Please provide a valid email address";
        document.getElementById("errormsg5").style.display = "block";
        return false;
    }

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Ritu001/kc2o3eb8/1/

Comment: Although your fiddle answers the question, your SO answer itself does not. It only shows validations, which is not what the question asked for

Answer (score 0):

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/cssapply.css">
<style type="text/css">


.error{
    color:darkgreen;} 
</style>
 
</head>
<body>
<form name="loginformjs" action="" onSubmit="return validate()" method="post">
<table  border="1" padding="2" cellpadding="2" width="20%" bgcolor="lightblue" align="center"
cellspacing="2">

<tr>
<td colspan=2>
<center><font size=4><p style="color: darkorange"><marquee direction="left" behavior="alternate" style="border:solid olive">Student Registration Form</marquee></p></font></center>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><p style="color: yellow">Firstname</p></td>
<td><p class="error"><input type="text" name="firstname" id="textname" size="20" value=""></p>
<span id ="error_firstname" class="error"></span></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><p style="color: orange">Lastname<html>
me</p></td>
<td><p class="error"><input type="text" name="lastname" id="textname" size="20" value=""></p>
<span id ="error_lastname" class="error"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>

<tr>
<td><p style="color: yellow">Address</p></td>
<td><p class="error"><input type="text" name="address"
id="address" size="20"></p>
<span id ="error_address" class="error"></span></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><p style="color: orange"> Gender</p></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" size="10" checked="checked">Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" size="10">Female
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><p style="color: yellow">City</td>
<td><p class="error"><select name="city">
<option value="0" selected>select city</option>
<option value="New Delhi">NEW DELHI</option>
<option value="Mumbai">MUMBAI</option>
<option value="Goa">GOA</option>
<option value="Patna">PATNA</option>
</select></p>
<span id ="error_city" class="error"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p style="color: orange">State</p></td>
<td><p class="error"><select Name="state" >
<option value="0" selected><p style="color: green">select state</p></option>
<option value="New Delhi">NEW DELHI</option>
<option value="Mumbai">MUMBAI</option>
<option value="Goa">GOA</option>
<option value="Bihar">BIHAR</option>
</select></p>
<span id ="error_state" class="error"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p style="color: yellow">Course</p></td>
<td><p class="error"><select name="course">
<option value="0" selected><p style="color: green">select course</p></option>
<option value="B.Tech">B.E</option>
<option value="MCA">MCA</option>
<option value="MBA">MBA</option>
<option value="BCA">BCA</option>
</select></p>
<span id ="error_course" class="error"></span></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><p style="color: orange">PinCode</p></td>
<td><p class="error"><input type="text" name="pincode" id="pincode" size="20"></p>
<span id ="error_pincode" class="error"></span></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><p style="color: yellow">EmailId</p></td>
<td><p class="error"><input type="text" name="emailid" id="emailid" size="20"></p>
<span id ="error_emailid" class="error"></span></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><p style="color: orange">DOB</p></td>
<td><p class="error"><input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" size="20"></p>
<span id ="error_dob" class="error"></span></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><p style="color: yellow">MobileNo</p></td>
<td><p class="error"><input type="text" name="mobileno" id="mobileno" size="20"></p>
<span id ="error_mobileno" class="error"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr><p style="color: orange"><td>
<p class="error">
     <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*"></p>
     <span id ="error_pic" class="error"></span></p></td></tr>
<tr>

<td colspan="1"><input type="submit" value="Submit Form" color="red"></td>
<td><input type="reset"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
  
<script type="text/javascript">

function validate() {
    
var err=0;

    var a = document.forms["loginformjs"]["firstname"].value;
    if (a == "") {
        //alert("please the enter firstname ");

        document.getElementById("error_firstname").innerHTML = "enter the firstname";
    err++;
    }
    else if(!/^[a-zA-Z]*$/g.test(document.loginformjs.firstname.value))
    {

        //alert("hello");
        document.getElementById('error_firstname').innerHTML="only alphanumeric character  required";
        document.loginformjs.firstname.focus();
        return false;
    }
else{
       document.getElementById("error_firstname").innerHTML = "";
    
    }

//alert("hello");
   var b = document.forms["loginformjs"]["lastname"].value;
    if (b == "") {
        //alert("please the enter lastname");
        document.getElementById("error_lastname").innerHTML = "enter the last name";
       err++;
      
    }

    else if(!/^[a-zA-Z]*$/g.test(document.loginformjs.lastname.value))
    {
        document.getElementById('error_lastname').innerHTML="only alphanumeric character  required";
        document.loginformjs.lastname.focus();
        return false;
    }

    else{
      document.getElementById("error_lastname").innerHTML = "";
    
    }

    var c = document.forms["loginformjs"]["address"].value;
    if (c == "") {
       // alert("please the enter address");
        document.getElementById("error_address").innerHTML = "enter the address";
        err++;
    }
    
       
    
    else if(!/^[0-9,./\-_ a-zA-Z''\s a-zA-Z0-9]*$/g.test(document.loginformjs.address.value))
    {
        document.getElementById('error_address').innerHTML="both digit and character required";
        document.loginformjs.address.focus();
        return false;
    }

    else{
      document.getElementById("error_address").innerHTML = "";
      
    }
   
  
    
    var e = document.forms["loginformjs"]["city"].value;
    if (e == "0") {
        //alert("please the city ");
        document.getElementById("error_city").innerHTML = "select city";
       err++;
    }
    

    else{
      document.getElementById("error_city").innerHTML = "";
      
    }
    var f = document.forms["loginformjs"]["state"].value;
    if (f == "0") {
        //alert("please the enter state ");
        document.getElementById("error_state").innerHTML = "select state";
        err++;

    }

    else
    {

      document.getElementById("error_state").innerHTML = "";
      
    }
    var g = document.forms["loginformjs"]["course"].value;
    if (g == "0") {
        //alert("please the enter course ");
        document.getElementById("error_course").innerHTML = "select course";
       err++;
    }

    else{
      document.getElementById("error_course").innerHTML = "";
      
    }
    var h = document.forms["loginformjs"]["pincode"].value;
    if (h == "") {
        //alert("please the enter pincode ");
        document.getElementById("error_pincode").innerHTML = "enter the   pincode";
        err++;
    }

    else if(!/^[1-9][0-9]{5}$/g.test(document.loginformjs.pincode.value))
    {
        document.getElementById('error_pincode').innerHTML="at least require six digit ";
        document.loginformjs.pincode.focus();
        return false;
    } 

    else{
      document.getElementById("error_pincode").innerHTML = "";
      
    }


   

 var j = document.forms["loginformjs"]["dob"].value;
    if (j == "") 
    {
        
        document.getElementById("error_dob").innerHTML = "enter your dob";
    err++;
    }
    else if(!/^(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{4})$/g.test(document.loginformjs.dob.value))
    {
        document.getElementById('error_dob').innerHTML="enter valid dob with - format";
        document.loginformjs.dob.focus();
        return false;
    } 
    else
    {
      document.getElementById("error_dob").innerHTML = "";
      
    }

    var k = document.forms["loginformjs"]["mobileno"].value;
    if (k == "") {
        //alert("please the enter mobileno");
        document.getElementById("error_mobileno").innerHTML = "enter your mobileno";
         err++;
        
    }
else if(!/^([0|\+[0-9]{1,5})?([7-9][0-9]{9})$/g.test(document.loginformjs.mobileno.value))
    {
        document.getElementById('error_mobileno').innerHTML="no start with 7,8,9 must contain";
        document.loginformjs.mobileno.focus();
        return false;
    } 


    else{
      document.getElementById("error_mobileno").innerHTML = "";
    }
    

    var l = document.forms["loginformjs"]["pic"].value;
    if (l == "") {
        //alert("please the enter image");
        document.getElementById("error_pic").innerHTML = "enter the image";
        err++;
    } 
    else if(!/(\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png))$/g.test(document.loginformjs.pic.value))
    {
        document.getElementById('error_pic').innerHTML="jpg,png,etc must contain";
        document.loginformjs.pic.focus();
        return false;
    } 


    else{
      document.getElementById("error_image").innerHTML = "";
      }
      
        

        if(err!=0){
           
        
        return false;
    }

    }

    </script>
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your code? Why do you think that it solves the problem? Which parts where neccessary? Please do not only post code, this makes it nearly impossible for the OP to spot his error